# Why does this Active Record where clause fetch the correct result if I'm passing it an object, not an attribute of the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm following along the Rails for Zombies tutorial trying to get the gist of RoR and how it runs. So far it's been a great compliment to the official Getting Started guide on the Rails website.

Here is a screenshot of the data I'm working with:

[image]

I run this clause and it works, but I don't understand why it's working:

```
z = Zombie.find(1)
w = Weapon.where(:zombie_id => z)
```

So in my mind, I read this as:

***Find me the weapons where Zombie_Id (a number!) is equal to z (a zombie object - not a number!)***

So how is this working? What am I missing here? Is RoR doing some magic behind the scenes with this where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build function in the [ActiveRecord::PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/predicate_builder.rb#L65) class used to build [where](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L156) (and various other) filters for ActiveRecord queries checks if the type being compared is an ActiveRecord::Model, if it is it compares the id:

```
def self.build(attribute, value)
    case value
    ...
    when ActiveRecord::Model
      attribute.eq(value.id)
    ...
    else
      attribute.eq(value)
    end
end
```

So yeah, Rails magic, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of fun stuff built into ActiveRecord, and in this case Active Record knows you're looking for :zombie_id, and it also knows what the zombie_id is through the Zombie model.  So it makes the assumption there. If you didn't send in a class Zombie, it would throw the error I believe.

Active Record has a lot of Reflection involved, and a lot of the helpers or macros would include this type of functionality for you for free.  That's why us ActiveRecord faithfuls love ActiveRecord so much!